# Call Angularjs Controller from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a project where I have two Controller 
register and Login.
how do I call Login Controller n success function of Registration.
This is my Controller

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $stateParams, ionicMaterialInk) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.$parent.clearFabs();
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.$parent.hideHeader();
  }, 0);
  ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
  $scope.Login = function(user) {
    Loginfunction($scope.user.username);
  };
});
```

and this is my registration Jquery Function which stores the data on the Server

```
function Registerfunction(user) {
  //alert(user.fname);
  var dataString = 'firstname=' + user.fname + 
      '&lastname=' + user.lname + 
      '&email=' + user.email + 
      '&password=' + user.password;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://seller.example.com/registerapp.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    success: function(msg) {
      alert('saba');
      //window.location.href="index.html";
      angular.element($("#login"))
        .scope()
        .callFromJquery('I Called You ! Angular !');
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

when I run this, It's giving me an error *angular.element(...).scope(...) is undefined*

How to solve this issue

Comment: Why don't you use angular's $http service to post data inside the controller?

Comment: you will make life very hard for yourself if you do not use `$http`

Comment: As others have said use `$http`. However as to your original issue i believe `Angular.element()` requires a raw DOM element or a string selector. Its purpose is to wrap things in a jQuery object (That it extends with methods such as `scope()`). However your passing it a jquery Object.

Comment: first, as said above, use `$http` and solve it automatically, but if you not want it, you should provide html with element with id _login_ and also controller where in scope added _callFromJquery_

Comment: can you try angular.element("div[ng-controller='yourControllerName']").scope() ?